# Mapping sums of defaultdict(list) to one list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, mapping, defaultdict

I have a large collection of data formatted somewhat like the `d.items()` of a `defaultdict(list)`. See below:

```
products = [(('blue'), ([2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4], [2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4], [2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4])),
        (('yellow'), ([1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3], [1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3], [1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3])),
        (('red'), ([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 4, 6, 4], [2, 5, 3, 4, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [8, 6, 3, 9, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]))]
```

And I want to map the sum of each data value in the nested lists to their corresponding counterparts in the same position or index to produce the final sums like follows:

```
['blue', 6, 12, 6, 12, 6, 12, 6, 12, '6.000000', 12]
['yellow', 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, '3.000000', 9]
['red', 11, 12, 7, 14, 11, 4, 7, 6, '8.000000', 6]
```

With loops, it can be done easily as shown in this function:

```
def summation(products):

    sums = []

    for item in products:
            sums.append([(item[0]),
                     sum(int(x[0]) for x in item[1]),
                     sum(int(x[1]) for x in item[1]),
                     sum(int(x[2]) for x in item[1]),
                     sum(int(x[3]) for x in item[1]),
                     sum(int(x[4]) for x in item[1]),
                     sum(int(x[5]) for x in item[1]),
                     sum(int(x[6]) for x in item[1]),
                     sum(int(x[7]) for x in item[1]),
                     "{:.6f}".format(sum(float(x[8]) for x in item[1])),
                     sum(int(x[9]) for x in item[1])])

    for s in sums:
        print(s)
```

The problem arises when the size of products is millions, i.e. it is very time-consuming. So I thought of implementing mapping each value to its corresponding one in the nested list for the same key. This is what I tried:

```
def mappingSum(products):
    sums = []

    for item in products:
        sums.append([item[0], map((sum(x), sum(y), sum(z)) for x, y, z in item[1])])



    for s in sums:
        print(s)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: map() must have at least two arguments.
```

I don't know how to resolve it and I am not sure whether `map` is the right tool to do my task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you need to *zip* the sublists in the list and sum them up:

```
>>> sums = [(key, [sum(value) for value in zip(*values)]) for key, values in products]
>>> for s in sums:
...     print(s)
... 
('blue', [6, 12, 6, 12, 6, 12, 6, 12, 6, 12])
('yellow', [3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9])
('red', [11, 12, 7, 14, 11, 4, 7, 6, 8, 6])
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to @alecxe's answer consider the following using `map` and a nice list literal-unpack:

```
res = [(k, [*map(sum, zip(*v))]) for k, v in products]
```

This yields:

```
[('blue', [6, 12, 6, 12, 6, 12, 6, 12, 6, 12]),
 ('yellow', [3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9]),
 ('red', [11, 12, 7, 14, 11, 4, 7, 6, 8, 6])]
```

This is slightly faster but requires Python `>= 3.5` due to the literal unpack. If on earlier versions, you'd have to wrap it in a `list` call to unpack the `map` iterator:

```
res = [(k, list(map(sum, zip(*v)))) for k, v in products]
```